# ExtJs 6.2 how to disable header function menu

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs6.2

I am using `ExtJS` 6.2 to create my table and I want to disable header menu, but I can't find it in document.

Please help me thanks.

[image]

I using `disableColumnHeaders()` this method work but has problem color will be different like picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`menuDisabled`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-menuDisabled) of [`Ext.grid.column.Column`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html) class

Here's the [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i91)